# HTML check boxes to add/remove entries on a many-to-many look up table (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, many-to-many

I have the following entities:

EMPLOYEE   (id, fname, lname, ...)

PROJECT (id, ...)

EMPLOYEE_PROJECT (employee_id, project_id, ...)

An employee can work on more than one project, and a project can be worked on by more than one employee, so the EMPLOYEE_PROJECT table is used to relate them.

I would like to generate in my application (PHP/MySQL) a form for a given PROJECT ID with a checkbox next to each employee name, that will display as checked if an entity for that employee id exists for that project id in the EMPLOYEE_PROJECT table, and that will allow the user to check or uncheck any employee and then click an "update" button to add/remove the selected/unselected employees from the project by adding/removing the entries on the EMPLOYEE_PROJECT table.

I am able to use an IF statement to display "checked" on any entity that exists in the EMPLOYEE_PROJECT table. My problems are:

1. Properly forming the query to get the list. If I get the list of employees by a JOIN of EMPLOYEE ON EMPLOYEE_PROJECT, it only shows employees who have been involved in a project, not all employees. I can do a LEFT JOIN to show all, but that would repeat names of employees who have multiple projects, and I only want to show each name once. If I add a GROUP BY employee.id, I can get a proper list of only one of each employee, however the results don't necessarily match the correct project_id. If I add a HAVING with the project_id, I lose employees who are not on the project (keep in mind I want to list ALL employees, but only show a check next to the ones that are currently on the project).
2. Assuming I figure out #1 and can list all employees and display a check next to the ones which exist as an EMPLOYEE_PROJECT entity for the specified project, how can I allow the check boxes to be modified by the user, and then submitted and have the one submit action add/remove the relevant entities from the EMPLOYEE_PROJECT table?

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@zzarbi is correct for #2. For #1 you need a sub-query:

```
SELECT employee.*, (SELECT count(id) FROM employee_project 
   WHERE project_id=<project_id> AND employee_id=employee.id) 
   AS in_project 
   FROM employee
```

Comment: Beautiful.. this is both what I love and what drives me nuts about trying to learn SQL. How did you know how to form that query? Is it all experience or do you have any specific learning recommendations? I'm gonna try to implement this now and see if I can get the #2 part to work as well. Thanks!

Comment: 10 years of trial and error :). I've also had some training classes and books along the way. I personally tend to learn best by example which is why I love this site so much :)

Answer (score 2):

For #1 "list ALL employees, but only show a check next to the ones that are currently on the project". (That work only if you show only one project at the time)

```
SELECT * from employee as e
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_PROJECT as ep on ep.employee_id = e.id
WHERE ep.project_id = <project id>
```

in php :

```
if("employee_id" IS NOT NULL/empty){
    echo "check";
}
```

For #2, usually my middle table project_employee has nothing else than two id (employeeId, projectId). So i generally just delete every employee for this projectId and re-add them.
If you have other data in the same table, this might not work. And you will have to compare old data store to new data to be stored.

Comment: Your query for #1 will only give you employees attached to the current project. All the employees brought in with the left join would be negated.

Comment: Thanks - the answer to #2 makes sense, I will try that. For #1, the query you gave still only shows employees that are on that specific project ID. I need to list ALL employees, and only check those on the project.

Comment: Oops, didn't refresh to see Cfreaks post before mine.

Comment: WHERE ep.project_id = <project id> OR ep.project_id IS NULL

Comment: @James - that still doesn't meet the criteria. Now you've got employees who are attached to the project in question or attached to no projects. You'd still be missing anyone who is attached to other projects.

Comment: Oops I forgot the "ep.project_id IS NULL"! which I was implying with the PHP code

Comment: Yep @Cfreak is right it doesn't return the one attached to other project